# atk4 model that retrieves data from external site

Tags: php, atk4

Is it possible to define a model to retrieve data from external site? I've seen that is pretty easy to use models to create some crud interfaces when data exists in local database. 
But what I would like to do is use some data provided by an external site api (in json format) based on a search form an then present it in tabular format just like MVCGrid so users can select some records to save them to local database.
I have the logic to retrieve the data in a controller, but I don't know how to use this controller from the model class to fill in all fields.

Comment: Sure it's possible! You can extend (or overwrite) some Model class methods, like load(), save() etc. Custom Controller is a way to go in this case too. But one thing you have to keep in mind is - use some caching mechanism! Otherwise your model will request external data on every initialization, every page load, every sorting, refresh and so on ... That way it'll become very slow and you can spam external API.

Comment: It seems that there is a better way to do what I need. Looking into model class I've found that there is a JSONRPC data controller which can be set for a model and it manages all requests and cache. I will investigate it.

Comment: Yeah there is, but I have not used that. If I remember correctly, then it was not completely finished some time ago when I needed to make external data import/synchronization for my project. But maybe I'm wrong. Have to check that myself too. Anyway, please let me know your results of investigation! :)

Answer (score 0):

Agile Toolkit 4.3 have completely new way of defining Data Sources. Here are some of the data controllers. Basically you just need to extend this class:

https://github.com/atk4/atk4/blob/4.3/lib/Controller/Data.php

Here are just some examples:

- https://github.com/atk4/atk4/blob/4.3/lib/Controller/Data/RESTful.php
- https://github.com/atk4/atk4/blob/4.3/lib/Controller/Data/PathFinder.php

JSONRPC does not really implement a CRUD-like access to a model, it is more of a transparent RPC, so I chose to display REST.